# Short jump out of range

Tags: nasm

I m having a problem with my loop, the code contained in it is long and it gives me error "short jump out of range", so i want to know if there is a way to make the loop work by not reducing the amount of code in it ?

example1:

```
label:
my code
    LOOP label
```

; It work fine but when I add more code in it

example2:

```
label:
my code
    more code added
    LOOP label
```

; It does not work and error appears "short jump out of range"

Answer (score 9):

The `LOOP` instruction can't jump to a distance of more than 127 bytes. You'll need to change your code to use `DEC ECX` with `JNZ` instructions.

For example:

```
    MOV ECX, 10
label:
    ;some codes
    LOOP label
```

Become:

```
    MOV ECX, 10
label:
    ;some codes
    DEC ECX
    JNZ label
```